# Angular2 syntax for SublimeText3

Tags: angular, sublimetext3

Recently I updated my SublimeText editor to build 3114 and he has problem to highlights syntax correctly.

For example

[image: this]

and

[image: this]

(Ng Model)] and the text in quotes is not highlighted. Before update all was fine. I use HTML syntax in SublimeText. Do you know any syntax package for HTML + angular2?

Comment: Please use Package Control's [search function](https://packagecontrol.io/search) to look for plugins. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: See my answer below. Now there is a syntax highlighter for angular2 html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a Angular2 HTML syntax highlighter in Package Control now:
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Angular2%20HTML%20Syntax

[image]